# How to search for filename throughout Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I want to search for a filename across all my commits/branches and find out which commits/branches contain that filename.  I don't know which subdirectory/subdirectories of the repo the file would be in.

I've tried `hg grep <filename>`, but that only seems to show files *containing* "`filename`".

I've also looked at [Mercurial - determine where file was removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419668/mercurial-determine-where-file-was-removed), but that really help me if a file was created on a different branch.  The person asking that question suggested `hg log myfile -v`, which seems like it could work, but doesn't.  I know that *somewhere* in my repo the file exists because I get something back when I do `find .hg | grep <filename>`, but that doesn't tell me (at least not clearly) which commits/branches.

Answer (score 4):

1. You have to read [`hg help patterns`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/patterns) and maybe [`hg help filesets`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/filesets) in order to write correct pattern for the file (most probably you'll be happy with just pattern)
2. **If** file **exist** now in working directory (i.e. was added and *not* removed later), you'll find it with `hg file <PATTERN>` and will determine full path by output, see above (pattern used)

`>hg file **/test-extra.t
 tests\test-extra.t`

and call `hg log` with full filename

3. **In any case** (`hg file` returned 0 for removed file or file still in WD) you can call `hg log <FILESET>` and get history too. Log for existing will be too long, will show deleted unique filename sample

`>hg log set:**/dulwich/tests/__init__.py -Tcompact
223   0b6c08800d16   2009-07-23 08:48 +0100   a
delete the dulwich fork we have`

`2   c43c02cc803a   2009-04-22 16:59 -0700   schacon
added dulwich library and got the script to call it for clone`

4. If your set will be too wide and (may) include files with the same name in different folders, you have to verify filenames by calling log with more details about files, f.e. with `-Tstatus`

Answer (score 2):

```
hg log 'glob:**/<filename>` -Tstatus
```

seems to do the job.  It doesn't give me the commits containing `<filename>`, but it does give commits (and their branches) involving `filename`.

Credit to Lazy Badger's answer for pointing me to this.